# Как справиться с ошибкой Lists are not currently supported in HTML input?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

У меня есть вложенный сериализатор:

```py
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = [
            'linkname',
            'linkurl'
        ]


    class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        links = LinkSerializer(
            many=True,
            # queryset = Link.objects.all()
        )
        class Meta:
            model = Work
            fields = [
                'firstname',
                'lastname',
                'links'
            ]
```

Модели выглядят следующим образом:

```py
class Work(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=10, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=30, blank=True)
  
    class Link(models.Model):
    links = models.ForeignKey(Work, related_name='links', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    linkname = models.CharField("linkname", max_length=100, blank=True)
    linkurl = models.CharField("linkurl", max_length=100, blank=True)
```

В django rest framework выводится следующее насчет `Links`:

> Links:
> Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.

Я поняла, что нужно поработать в сторону json для вложенных сериализаторов, однако не выходит, поэтому прошу помощи, как бы вы поступили с этой проблемой.
Заранее спасибо тому, кто поможет

Я прикрепила скриншот к вопросу, взгляните пожалуйста:

[image: Json ??]